# Using Eclipse (Neon 3, 64 bit) on Windows 10, how do I bring (or keep) the Console window in view?

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-neon

Using the installer, I installed Eclipse Neon 3 (64 bit) on to my Windows 10 workstation.  To get going and test my install, I ran simple "hello world" app.  The trouble was that I expected the Console window to show my output.

I did see the console window open, but instantly disappear again.  Nothing I do will keep this window open in the IDE.  Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

On my hunt for an answer I read [an old post re: no console output](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/197552/) that led me to downloading the 32 bit version.  This solved the problem.  [Bug 516182](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=516182) logged.